# Stuck at logo screen while booting

Tags: boot

I have Ubuntu installed on a Gateway NV53A laptop with Windows 7 removed, and recently when I've tried to start the computer, it gets stuck at the logo screen that says "Ubuntu" with the progress bar lights.

I recently upgraded to 13.04.

I'm able to start by going to advanced options in the GRUB menu and then selecting recovery mode and then hitting F, but I have to do this each time I start.  It also seems like it doesn't work as well this way.

Comment: Thanks. I'm having other problems though like Google Chrome and Firefox don't open when I'm able to start it up. Is there a way to repair broken files or features? It seems like something went wrong when I upgraded.

Answer (score 0):

Boot in recovery mode. Type `sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm` in the terminal and choose the `lightdm`. Reboot your system in the normal way.

Comment: Thanks.  I'm having other problems though like Google Chrome and Firefox don't open when I'm able to start it up.  Is there a way to repair broken files or features?  It seems like something went wrong when I upgraded.

Comment: Type `sudo dpkg --configure -a` or `sudo apt install -f` to repair broken packages.