# Ubuntu 14.04 does not start since I stopped BleachBit process

Tags: 14.04, boot

My Ubuntu 14.04 does not start. The logo appears but it proceeds no further.

[image: plymouth loading screen]

When I choose **Advanced Options for Ubuntu** in the GRUB menu, I reach this menu:

[image: recovery menu]

What should I do?

Comment: Welcome to [ubuntu.se]! What have you done before? Is Ubuntu freshly installed or have you used it already? Have you done any changes in the OS configuration (including updates) recently? Please check similar questions ([Stuck at logo screen while booting](https://askubuntu.com/q/309546/250300); [Installation/live booting stuck on logo](https://askubuntu.com/q/887294/250300)) and examine whether your problem is mentioned there or what differs in your case.

Comment: Are you able to enter the grub menu?

Comment: Before this problem, i stopped the bleachbit software before it ended because it takes long time.

Comment: Yes i enter to the grub menu

Comment: this problem appears just after i stopped the bleachbit because it takes long times.

Answer (score -1):

You can do it through recovery mode

restart the machine

press shift continous until start with recovery mode

select advance mode

then select recovery image enter it

follow the process

after reboot

you machine working fine

Comment: i press shift after appear the grub menu ?

Comment: it will appear menu with

Comment: ubuntu                                                                                                                                advance    ---------so need to enter on advance option

Comment: Follow what process?

Comment: what process i do  "zanna" please ?

Comment: @azdine I don't know, and Mayur Bhandare hasn't told us yet. You have various options in recovery mode, and I don't know which one is indicated in your scenario. Possibly attempting to fix broken packages may assist.

Comment: it appears between the grub menu and the screen at the top this message : [drm: intel_set_pch_fifo_underrun_reporting [i915] *ERROR* uncleared pch fifo underrun on pch transcoder A
 [drm: intel_pch_fifo_underrun_irq_handler [i915] *ERROR* PCH transcoder A FIFO underrun

Comment: you can repair broken packages here

Comment: please select dpkg after that resume the system

Comment: when i select 'resume'  it appears  a black screen with cursor

Comment: press CTRL + ALT + F4 then login using your username and password

#sudo apt-get purge lightdm
#sudo apt-get update
#sudo apt-get install lightdm
#dpkg-reconfigure lightdm
Now type #sudo shutdown -r now to restart.